# How to design a window form as in the attached screen shot?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to design a window form as in the attached screen shot.

I want panels (left, right, center and bottom) like screen shot with options (close, and etc).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sliding panels that VS uses are not standard .NET controls.  You would have to either create your own or else use a third-party component, e.g.

https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite

Answer (score 1):

Add four panel panel1 st have doc property left, second has right, third has bottom and fourth should be full. I hope this idea fix your problem